# Is there anyway to convert emoji to text in Java?

Tags: java, emoji

how can I convert emojis like this to text? I mean to convert a happy face to the words "happy" and so on. Using Java, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to set up a map between the unicode character and your word

Comment: Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried any code because I had no idea on how to do so. Now I know thankfully.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use [emoji4j](https://github.com/kcthota/emoji4j) library.

```
String text = "A ,  and a  became friends❤️. For 's birthday party, they all had s, s, s and .";

EmojiUtils.shortCodify(text); //returns A :cat:, :dog: and a :mouse: became friends:heart:. For :dog:'s birthday party, they all had :hamburger:s, :fries:s, :cookie:s and :cake:.
```

Comment: your library is very good +1 but i wanted just unicode like "\uD83D\uDC4D" is java unicode for   . Do you have any function for it in your library ?

Comment: :slightly_smiling_face: - fail

Answer (score 1):

Since that emoji is simply a standard Unicode code point (`U+1F601`, see [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f601/index.htm)), probably the best way is to set up a map which translates them into strings.

By way of example, here's a piece of code that creates a string-to-string map to allow you to look up and translate that exact code point:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
class Xyzzy {
    public static Map<String,String> xlat = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        xlat.put("\uD83D\uDE01", "happy");
        System.out.println(xlat.get("\uD83D\uDE01"));
    }
}
```

You can add as many code points to the map as you wish, and use `Map.get()` to extract the equivalent text for any of them.

Comment: A quick noob question: Can you give me an example to start with? Thanks.

Comment: @Rahul, no problem. See the update for an example of using map.